# Handling database table fields in php - Creating dynamic table using php

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I would like to create a dynamic table with fields like this.

```
    table_name: book_list

    book1(int(2))   book2(int(2))....   book44(int(2)
```

I have a php code like this.

```
    <?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    for($i=1;$i<=44;$i++){

    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book_list` (
      book_'.$i. 'int(2) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1';

    mysql_select_db('book_db');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    }
    ?>
```

The above code needs some tweaks, that is to be done for generating the dynamic table.

Any help will be more appreciable.

Thanks,
Kimz

PS: I know the MYSQL is getting depreciated but still this is for my client and he wants only mysql and not pdo or mysqli. looks crazy. but still

Comment: Once table get created you need a alter query to add more columns.

Comment: yup, how? i'm not big into php and loops. could you help with the above code.

Comment: do you want to create new table or add column in existing table?

Comment: add column.. my for loop is really bad. but still..

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: yes kermit. you are right. but my client is not willing to use mysqli or pdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start building your query outside of the for-loop and then just loop over the fields you want. Something like this (not tested):

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book_list` (';

for($i=1;$i<=44;$i++){
    $sql .= 'book_'.$i. ' int(2) NOT NULL';
    if($i < 44) {
        $sql .= ', ';
    }
}

$sql .= ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1';

mysql_select_db('book_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

?>
```

Comment: wow, wow. wow. excellent. one more thing is . the code is simply superb. one small change. change $sql .= 'book_'.$i. ' int(2) NOT NULL' to $sql .= 'book_'.$i. ' int(2) NOT NULL';

Answer (score 0):

You can use some ORM tools, e.g. http://redbeanphp.com/

But the best option is use 3NF of database.

Instead adding bookNo as column to table, add column Number

sample.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book_list` (
   number int(2) NOT NULL 
   book int(2) NOT NULL
)
```

#### References

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form